# SQLIte not displaying all of the results correctly in ListView

Tags: sqlite, listview, search, android-listview, android-search

I am having trouble with displaying the results in the search activity of my app. I wonder where it went wrong.

The aim of the function below is to search the input query of the user and find it in every files listed. But the results only matches one data eventhough the query is also present in the other files. Here is the code.

```
 public void searchFiles(File[] filelist, String query, String querysearch, String[] namesOfFiles){
    querysearch = "SELECT * FROM Data WHERE ObjectID = ? ";
    int temp2 = filelist.length;
    for (int i = (temp2-1); i >= 0; i--) {
        if(!(filelist[i].getName().equals("DataObjectDB.db")) && !(filelist[i].getName().endsWith("-journal"))){
            temp1 = filelist[i].getName();
            namesOfFiles[i] = temp1.replaceAll(".db$", "");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Searching " + query + " in: " + namesOfFiles[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DatabaseHelper db1 = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext(),namesOfFiles[i]);
            SQLiteDatabase sqldb = db1.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(querysearch, new String[]{query});
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cursor.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_listview);
    SearchAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, R.layout.results_column, cursor,0 );
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The searchFiles() function passes the filelist, query, querysearch and namesOfFiles where 1) filelist contains the list of files in the source folder 2) query is the user input he/she wants to search 3) querysearch is the select statement 3) namesofFiles is just an empty string.

I indicate a toast to see if the code traverses through all the folders. And yes it is. But I don't know why it is not displaying all the results.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Oh no, I pasted the unedited code, but thank you! Anyway, I have just re-posted the basic select statement code. Nonetheless, it's still giving the wrong results.

Comment: I don't understand why are you messing with files? Isn't it enough to give in the database path and name?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Those are database files containing the tables. For example, I have a file named "File1", it contains tables such as 1) "Data" containing the columns "ObjectID", "Value", and "Property" 2)"Settings" containing "Lock"  and others 3) other tables. So I want to search in each files' "data" table.

Comment: It seems an overkill, to me... Why not having a single database with multiple tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on different posts. Basically, you just have to use hashmap and arraylist first before setting up the adapter directly.